# More insulting form of "placate"

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like there's a word that I can't quite find, where you are placating someone, but more out of duty or responsibility than for care.

For example, when a person in the service industry must placate an irate customer whose anger far exceeds whatever offense was caused, but they are bound by policy to act like they understand and agree. Something similar to 'patronize.' The word would be said with derision.

Comment: I tried to think of a word to pacify you, but nothing came to mind.

Comment: Appeasing carries that for me

Comment: @Unrelated Appeasing seems to imply that _not doing so_ will result in (unwanted) backlash from the other party. "Appeasing an angry god" is the first example that comes to mind.

Comment: Did you check ou a thesaurus? What of those suggested didn't work for you?

Comment: Describe exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase--generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done. List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: Also note if the criterion for accepting answers is "if you can guess which word I've forgotten and am trying to remember", that's not a fair question. It's what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. ([more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/))

Comment: Appease seems the closest to what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

*Pacify* would appear to work.

Definition of pacify (from [Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pacify))

> **pacified; pacifying**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> 1. a : to allay the anger or agitation of : **soothe** • *pacify* a crying child
>      b : **appease, propitiate** • tried to *pacify* the enemy with compromises

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the post directly above. My bad.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to convert a comment-in-an-answer into a real answer.

Comment: Now I will just always stare at your reputation and know 30 of those points could have been mine! ;)

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer. I am trying to get the hang of this forum. Now I understand a little better what the expectations are. I think.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with

> humour

or if I was feeling particularly mean and wanted to make them feel stupid

> propitiate

;D